# Why search is not working in Detail page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a Shows.jsx componente that render all the shows. I have a component ProductDetails that render the information about 1 show. And I have a Search component that is a searchbar that I want that filter by name.

This is the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  error: false,
  products: [],
  product: {},
  allProducts: [],
  filteredProducts: [],
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case GET_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload,
        allProducts: action.payload,
        filteredProducts: action.payload,
      };
      
      case SEARCH:   
        console.log("search",  action.payload);
        return {
          ...state,
          products: action.payload,
        };
```

This is action:

```
export const search = (name) => {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    try {
      let info = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/products/?name=" + name); // ############   ACA VA LA RUTA PARA SOLICITAR EL GET
      //let searchRes = info.filter((e) => e.name.includes(name));
      console.log('info.data en action', info.data);
      return dispatch({
        type: "SEARCH",
        payload: info.data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return "No pudimos encontrar ese producto";
    }
  };
}
```

This is Search:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./SearchBar.css";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useHistory, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import * as actions from "../../redux/actions";

import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import Error_Search from './Error_Search.jpg'

function Search() {
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();
  const products = useSelector(state => state.products)

  const showAlertNoEnter=()=> {
    Swal.fire({
      //icon:'warning',
      imageUrl: Error_Search,
      imageHeight: 150,
      imageWidth: 200,
      imageAlt: 'Hubo un error en la búsqueda.',
      title: 'Buscador de Yazz', 
      html:'<h3>Por favor, ingresá un nombre</p>', 
      footer:'<p>Probá de nuevo.</p>'
    }
    )
  }

  const showAlertNoName=()=> {
    Swal.fire({
      //icon:'warning',
      imageUrl: Error_Search,
      imageHeight: 150,
      imageWidth: 200,
      imageAlt: 'Hubo un error en la búsqueda.',
      title: 'Buscador de Yazz', 
      html:'<h3>Esa banda no tiene ningún show programado</p>', 
      footer:'<p>Probá con otra banda.</p>'
    }
    )
  }

  function handleInputChange(e) {
    //setea el name con lo que va escribiendo el usuario
   // e.preventDefault();
      setName(e.target.value);
      let filtered = products.filter(
      (p) => p.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
      );
      setSuggestions(filtered);
  }

  function handleSearch(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      if (!name) {
      showAlertNoEnter();
      return;
    }
    
    dispatch(actions.search(name));
    setName("");//vacia el input
    setSuggestions([]); 
    history.push("/shows");
   //<Redirect to='/shows' />
  }

  function handleSuggestionClick(name) {
    //history.push(`/product/${id}`);
//    history.push("/shows");
     dispatch(actions.search(name));
     setName("");//vacia el input
    setSuggestions([]); 
     history.push("/shows");
  }

  return (
    <div className="searchContainer">
      <div className="search_inputSuggest">
        <input
          id="search"
          className="searchBar"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Buscar por nombre"
          onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
          value={name}
        />
        <div className="search_suggestion_div">
        <datalist className="suggestionsList">
          {suggestions.slice(0, 10).map(s => ( //shows just 10 suggestions
            <option className="suggestionsList_item" key={s.id} onClick={() => handleSuggestionClick(s.name)}>
              {s.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </datalist>
      </div>
      </div>
      <button className="btnSearch" onClick={(e) => handleSearch(e)}>
        Buscar
      </button>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

The Search is working ok when we use it on the Shows page. However, if we use it on a Detail page it doesn't filter and render all the shows.

How can I make it work from everywhere?

Comment: Where is the search bar component located in terms of app structure?

Comment: @EkkoKo Search is a component that I import into the NavBar component.

Comment: I see that you're using react router, are you using it inside of every page or in an outlet?

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by "an outlet"? We use it in App.js and on the components where we need to Link something.

Comment: I meant where do you import the navbar in your app structure? 
do you import it in every page or do you import it and have an outlet that will render every page but you only mention the search bar above it.
what outlet do is simply let you nest your UI

Comment: We imported Navbar in App.js. unction App() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Route exact path={"/"} component={LandingPage} />
      {pathname !== "/" ? <NavBar /> : null}
      <Route exact path={"/shows"} component={Shows} />
      <Route path="/product/:id">
        <ProductDetails />
      </Route>
      {pathname !== "/" ? <Footer /> : null}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

Comment: Okay, I see now so you're importing it before the pages, first thing first I would recommend you to read about react router outlets, that talks about how to implement a layout for a website with their recommended approach 
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet

Comment: What is a "shows" or "detail" page? What is different between these two pages/components that the `Search` component works in one and not the other? Can you [edit] the post to clarify the issue in better detail and provide a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: @EkkoKo OP is using `react-router-dom@5`, so saying to use an `Outlet` and linking to the RRDv6 docs won't help the OP at all.

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, it seems that on the first render of `Search` component you don't get an initial products data, therefore it will be empty when you try to filter it in the `handleInputChange` function, or perhaps if you've searched for something already so in the products you will have all the values that the search returned you might which is a semi not fully list of products that have the name that you've serached.

And I'm guessing that in `/shows` page you have a function that gets all shows and store them in the redux state and that's why you have a full search and filtering that is working properly.

So a good way to fix this search issue is on the `Search` Component or the initial redux state get the array of all the shows.

Comment: Actually in Search we have:  const products = useSelector(state => state.products) And we use that to get all the Shows from the initial state.